# How to enable CORS Headers for a Lambda Integration in AWS API Gateway, using the API Gateway API?

Tags: cors, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have forked the [Lambada framework](https://github.com/cagataygurturk/lambadaframework) and started modifying it to add support for CORS headers. Lambada utilizes the API Gateway API [sic] to configure the API Gateway.

As a proof-of-concept, I manually verified the necessary changes in API Gateway console, and then went looking for the corresponding steps in the automation code. I started by making this simple change to `org.lambadaframework.aws.ApiGateway` (imports omitted for brevity):

[image]

I rebuilt the framework successfully. Unfortunately when I try to deploy a new Lambda using it, I get:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.lambadaframework:lambada-maven-plugin:0.0.6-cors:deploy (default)
>   on project MyApp: Exception at deployment: Invalid
>   mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors
>   : [Invalid mapping expression specified: Access-Control-Allow-Origin]
>   (Service: A mazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   BadRequestException; Request ID: 16509b8e-30eb-11e9-bc6b-f5d1416f03b5)
>   -> [Help 1]

What could cause this to fail?! I have performed the same steps manually (through the ApiGateway console) and it works fine in there. Ultimately, how can I get CORS Headers enabled?

Similar question, using CLI: [api gateway CORS setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35228488/api-gateway-cors-setup)

Comment: it should be `map.put("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")` why you use Boolean.FALSE ??

Comment: @RajarshiDas ok I tried removing the single-quotes and changed Boolean.FALSE to Boolean.TRUE. Nothing changes. The error message is EXACTLY the same. Any other ideas? API documentation can be found here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/services/apigateway/model/PutMethodResponseRequest.html if that helps.

Comment: map.put("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*") use it for both...there is no true or false for this

Comment: @RajarshiDas that won’t even compile. Please look more closely at the code.

Comment: @RajarshiDas the PutMethodResponseRequest::withResponseParameters requires a Map<String,Boolean>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integration response template does not need to be set in this situation when you set integration response parameters.

If you like to use integration response for modifying the response, you specify a content type as key and the response template as value. <sup>[2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html)</sup>

Say you wanted to modify responses of content type `"application/json"`, your implementation will be like:

```
/* replace the existing getResponseTemplate() method with this */
private Map<String, String> getResponseTemplate() {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put(
        "application/json",
        "$input.json(\"$\")\n#set($context.responseOverride.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin = \"*\")");
    return params;
}
```

Comment: the PutIntegrationResponseRequest::withResponseParameters requires a Map<String,String>, while PutMethodResponseRequest::withResponseParameters requires a Map<String,Boolean>

Comment: So your modified getIntegrationResponseParameters() causes a compilation error in the call to PutIntegrationResponseRequest::withResponseParameters

Comment: I'm going to try your idea anyway assuming you just got the method names wrong...

Comment: I think maybe it got worse: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.lambadaframework:lambada-maven-plugin:0.0.6-cors:deploy (default) on project boilerplate: Exception at deployment: Invalid ma
pping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: *, Invalid mapping expression specified: integrati
on.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin] (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: e378611f-34db-11e9-b5
9a-8b06fa5a2f86) -> [Help 1]

Comment: You're correct! `PutIntegrationResponseRequest` is documented differently. I'll edit my answer to reflect my current understanding of the API

Comment: Event though this is failing, I feel it is somehow closer to an answer. I pushed my changes here: https://github.com/atramos/lambadaframework/commit/88bd12b7d6ac5a9e29316b55aabcc76e756795d8

Comment: so now you got rid of `getMethodResponseParameters`? I'll try that. BTW that asterisk has to be single-quoted, otherwise another error.

Comment: `PutIntegrationResponseRequest.withResponseParameters` is stil causing the same error, `Invalid mapping expression specified: integration.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: OMG the getResponseTemplates was it. I edited your answer to keep only the minimum required change.